# Quick select - shuffle to make sorting faster

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

I'm trying to use shuffle to improve worse case scenario of quick select (e.g. every time, selected pivot value is the largest, so each iteration, only one elements could be removed from judgement).

My solution to this problem is to use shuffle, but I am not sure if using shuffle still have small chance (during every shuffle). The selected pivot is happening to be the largest element.

Any advice on algorithm time complexity improvement, code bugs or general code style advice is highly appreciated.

The entry point of my code is `quick_select_k_largest`, which tries to get `k-th` largest element from a list, and the 1st largest element from the list is max value element of the list (i.e. `k` starts from 1 other than 0).

```
import random
def shuffle(numbers, start, end):
    if start == end:
        return
    for i in range(start+1, end+1):
        index = random.randint(start,i-1)
        numbers[index], numbers[i] = numbers[i], numbers[index]

def quick_select_k(numbers, start, end, k):
    shuffle(numbers, start, end)
    pivot = numbers[end]
    i = start
    j = end - 1
    while i <= j:
        while i <= j and numbers[i] <= pivot:
            i += 1
        while numbers[j] > pivot:
            j -= 1
        if i < j:
            numbers[i], numbers[j] = numbers[j], numbers[i]
    numbers[i], numbers[end] = numbers[end], numbers[i]
    if i == k:
        return numbers[k]
    elif i > k:
        return quick_select_k(numbers, start, i-1, k)
    else:
        return quick_select_k(numbers, i+1, end, k)
def quick_select_k_largest(numbers, k):
    index = len(numbers) - k
    return quick_select_k(numbers, 0, len(numbers)-1, index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = []
    for i in range(10):
        numbers.append(random.randint(0,20))
    k = random.randint(1,10)
    print quick_select_k_largest(numbers, k)
    print k, sorted(numbers)
```